# Security exception while using wsimport

Tags: java, exception, ssl, ant, wsimport

I want to generate stub files from a wsdl file which is reachable over a ssl connection with a self-signed certificate.

```
<exec executable="wsimport">
<arg value="-d" />
<arg value="${absolute.path.to.project}/gen" />
<arg value="-s" />
<arg value="${absolute.path.to.project}/src" />
<arg value="https://host:8443/wsrf/services/WS?wsdl" />
</exec>
```

When I execute this in ant, I get this error:

```
generate-from-wsdl:
     [exec] parsing WSDL...
     [exec] [ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
     [exec] Failed to read the WSDL document: https://192.168.56.101:8443/wsrf/services/KnowledgebaseWebservice?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.
     [exec] [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 
     [exec]  At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
     [exec]     Failed to parse the WSDL.
     [exec] Result: 1
```

To avoid this, I tried to

- Import the server.crt file with `keytool -importcert -file ~/path/server.crt`
- Copying the server.crt to $JAVA_HOME/lib/security

**UPDATE**

I've also tried the following:

```
<wsimport wsdl="https://host:8443/Webservice?wsdl" destdir="gen"
              sourcedestdir="src"
              verbose="true">
    <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/host.cer" />
    <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" />
</wsimport>
```

I still get this error. What could I do?

Comment: Does Ant execute as same user which you did the `keytool -import` for?

Comment: I fear not :-) the import was performed as root (sudo), ant as normal user... But I'm working on another solution a.t.m. which I will post here if it works

Comment: You could download a local copy of the WSDL (and any referenced XSD files) and then generate your stubs from the local copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will need to import the server cert into the JRE's keystore by specifying `-keystore <path_to>/jre/lib/security/cacerts`. If you stick with your previous command line, I think you'll need to execute that command for the same user who executes Ant.

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.grim.se/guide/jre-cert) outlines steps for importing the server cert into the JRE keystore with `keytool.exe` for those unfamiliar with the process as I was.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot import cert to my /jre/lib/security/cacerts.

So I ended up with the following workaround:

```
<target name="main" >
    <exec executable="java">
        <arg line="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\jdk160_29\.mykeystore  -classpath C:\jdk160_29\lib\tools.jar com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport https://host:8443/Webservice?wsdl -p com.test -s ./src"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Where did you put this target tag?